# Install Boost correctly into Qt (failing currently with permission denied)

Tags: c++, qt, boost

What I am trying to do is install Boost into Qt correctly so that I can use it in any Qt program.

However currently building is failing with these issues:

```
cannot find /: Permission denied
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiler Output :

```
12:55:12: Running steps for project boostQtExample...
12:55:12: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
12:55:12: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe"
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Nick.CSM3D/Downloads/build-boostQtExample-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug\boostQtExample.exe debug/main.o debug/mainwindow.o debug/moc_mainwindow.o -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -LC:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/mingw491_32/lib -lqtmaind -LC:\mingw491\mingw32\lib -LC:\Utils\icu32_53_1_mingw482\lib -LC:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib -LC:\utils\mysql\mysql\lib -LC:\opensll\lib -lshell32 -LC:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\mingw491_32/lib -LC:\releases\lib\boost\boost_qt\stage\lib\ / -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored
C:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find /: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Debug:81: recipe for target 'debug\boostQtExample.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\boostQtExample.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Nick.CSM3D/Downloads/build-boostQtExample-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
12:55:15: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project boostQtExample (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Boost was installed by using this websites step by step process, http://cpp-qt-mac-win.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/qt-boost-for-beginners-step-by-step.html?view=mosaic, currently using the Qt example on this page to test if my setup is working (which it isn't). This includes building of the library files, and I have also set the enviroment variables in windows (C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin;C:\releases\lib\boost\boost_qt\stage\lib).

```
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2011-10-24T19:30:35
#
#-------------------------------------------------
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = boostQtExample
TEMPLATE = app

#Dont forget to add the path to your boost install folder
INCLUDEPATH += C:\releases\lib\boost\boost_qt


LIBS += -LC:\releases\lib\boost\boost_qt\stage\lib\ \
        -lboost_datetime

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Does anyone have any suggestions in what else I'm missing ?

Comment: Try wrapping up your paths in quotation marks. I.e. "C:\releases\lib\boost\boost_qt\stage\lib\"

Comment: I think you used the wrong slash at the end of your `LIBS +=` line. Line continuations are made with backslashes.

Comment: Brill knew it was something stupid just couldn't see it. However now building this returns this issue: :-1: error: cannot find -lboost_datetime. Is there any way I can get this to work without directly linking the static library? As have lots of libraries I want to test so would make my life 10 x easier.

Answer (score 0):

Changing LIBS += / to LIBS += \ solved this problem. However instead is now just reporting ":-1: error: cannot find -lboost_datetime". Will create a new question to solve this problem.